# Winforms option in Visual Studio Code

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-code

I'm relatively new to Visual Studio Code and currently running the latest version.
Looking to create a WinForm file where I can drag and drop controls to develop a GUI app however I can't find the option to create it.
Referred to multiple articles online which talks about 'Creating a new project' however, the option is not available in my Visual Studio Code. I have also installed C# extension and .Net SDK but nothing helped.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: `dotnet new winforms` + `dotnet run`? No designer. Why don't you get Visual Studio Community edition instead? All the stuff you need is included and ready to go.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. This helped.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Visual Studio Community edition helped resolve my query